# Pjsua2.so with tls support, couldn't load to android project

Tags: android, ssl, voip, pjsip, tls1.2

I'm trying to enable tls in pjsip and load it to android project. 
In order to do it I'm building pjsip with openssl support. I downloaded openss binary from https://github.com/emileb/OpenSSL-for-Android-Prebuilt.
I set

```
./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags --with-ssl=path_to_folder
```

After that I tried to build pjsip, everything is ok.

I added libssl.so, libcrypto.so, pjsua2.so to android studio project.
When I tried to load pjsua2.so:

```
static {
    loadLibrary("pjsua2");
}
```

I got error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libssl.so.1.0.0" needed by "libpjsua2.so"; caused by library "libssl.so.1.0.0" not found
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: maybe path to libssl.so is not correct ?

Answer (score 0):

After you add de Openssl you have to compile pjproject again. In the comand make you should get some error of path. If you add the -L and -I properly you should not get problems and it compiles and work fine...

Comment: fixed with the help of rpl utility

Comment: @Pein i am facing the same issue, can you please tell me how you solved it?